# BackgroundService not shutting down, stoppingToken never set with .net core generic host

Tags: c#, .net-core, background-service, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I have a BackgroundService hosted in .net generic host as follows:

```
var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);

builder
    .ConfigureLogging((hostingContext, logging) =>
    {
        logging.ClearProviders();
        logging.AddConsole();
        if(hostingContext.HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment() == true)
            logging.AddDebug();
    })
    .ConfigureHostConfiguration(configurationBuilder =>
    {
        configurationBuilder.AddCommandLine(args);
    })
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, configApp) =>
    {
        var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
        Console.WriteLine(env.EnvironmentName);
    })
    .UseConsoleLifetime();
```

I then have my worker:

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        // here i am doing something with ClientWebSocket, threads etc
        // snipped for brevity. I want to avoid spinning in a loop

        // the debugger reaches the following line
        WaitHandle.WaitAny(new[] { stoppingToken.WaitHandle });

        // but never hits this line
        this.logger.LogInformation("shutting down worker");
    }
}
```

On ctrl+c from the windows terminal of the running app it says `Application is shutting down` (this is from the framework) however the stoppingToken never gets set (so i cant shutdown my worker).

How and when does stoppingToken get set, and how can i gracefully terminate my worker?

The console

Comment: Wouldn't you just do:  while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested) { await Task.Delay(100, stoppingToken); }

Comment: @DanielLorenz i have added some context to the code, i have some background threads and event handlers that run themselves... even snipping this out the stoppingToken is never set.  I want to avoid spinning in a loop if possible.

Comment: But that is the whole purpose of a BackgroundService.  You need to keep doing something over and over again.  If you do something once, then just let the process end and don't call that WaitHandle as yo don't care?

Comment: Yes it's receiving messages constantly via web socket and forwarding on, it must stay alive constantly in the loop. I can certainly poll in a tight loop for `stopping token.IsCancellationRequested==true` but I would like to use the cancellation token on some of the snipped codes async function calls (that take a CancellationToken as a parameter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For BackgroundServices, they need to continue running until the cancellation token says to stop.  To do that, you need a while loop.  However, when you pass this cancellation token into any Async method, it will stop that method from running all the way through the chain if you use that same token in all the layers.  It should look something like this:

```
  protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // here i am doing something with ClientWebSocket, threads etc
            // snipped for brevity. I want to avoid spinning in a loop
            ... 
            await client.DownloadAsync(..., stoppingToken);
            ...
        }

        // but never hits this line
        this.logger.LogInformation("shutting down worker");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks mate, i ended up just putting a tight spin on `while(!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)  {  await Task.Delay(1000);  }` to be honest not sure why if i sleep on stoppingToken with `WaitHandle.WaitAny(new[] { stoppingToken.WaitHandle });` it never wakes up - am I doing something wrong with thread blocking?

Comment: @g18c I think it hangs there because the cancellation request of the token goes down but it never comes back up because your line is blocking it.  At least, that is my assumption.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so:

```
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10), stoppingToken);
```