# BackgroundService never started/stopped if no await done

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, background-service, ihostedservice

On ASP.NET Core I'm observing a strange behavior, that was actually reported in [BackgroundService not shutting down, stoppingToken never set with .net core generic host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61109752/backgroundservice-not-shutting-down-stoppingtoken-never-set-with-net-core-gene) but without the root cause ever being found

I'm creating the following `BackgroundService` task, registered as a `HostedService` :

The only method is implemented like so :

```
 protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 {
     while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested )
         Console.WriteLine("running");
 }
```

If I try to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or kill -15 this, it is *not* stopping.

If I change the function like this:

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested )
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("running");
        await Task.Delay(1);
    }
}
```

This works: if I try to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> this program, the cancellation token is set, and I exit.

If I go back to the version that doesn't work and pause it, I see that even though I'm in the ExecuteAsync method, the frame below it is StartAsync(), which in that case never completed!

The code I see for StartAsync() (from the framework), is this one:

```
public virtual Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Store the task we're executing
    _executingTask = ExecuteAsync(_stoppingCts.Token);

    // If the task is completed then return it, this will bubble cancellation and failure to the caller
    if (_executingTask.IsCompleted)
    {
        return _executingTask;
    }

    // Otherwise it's running
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

So, what is going on here ?

I have 2 questions:

1. Why is ExecuteAsync not run from the start in another thread on the thread pool ? I would assume the call to `_executingTask = ExecuteAsync(_stoppingCts.Token);` would immediately return but apparently it's not the case, and it's waiting for the first await to execute the line just after
2. Is my code of `BackgroundService` incorrect ? AFAIK it's a legal use-case to use purely blocking code in async function, it shouldn't lead to the whole application forever blocking

Comment: actually I think I found the relevant github issue : https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/36063

Comment: _"AFAIK it's a legal use-case to use purely blocking code in async function,"_ - while technically you can do that, you never should.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is pretty much covered in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio#backgroundservice-base-class):

> `ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken)`is called to run the background service. The implementation returns a `System.Threading.Tasks.Task` that represents the entire lifetime of the background service. No further services are started until [`ExecuteAsync` becomes asynchronous](https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/issues/2149), such as by calling `await`. Avoid performing long, blocking initialization work in `ExecuteAsync`.

The simple fix is to just call `await Task.Yield()` at the start of `ExecuteAsync`:

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await Task.Yield();
    // ... rest of the code
}
```

Note that your initial implementation should produce a warning complaining about lacking `await` which is hinting that you are potentially doing something [not entirely correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37595260/2501279).

Comment: What's the advantage of using `Task.Yield()` over `Task.CompletedTask`?

Comment: @MetroSmurf you mean in case of `await Task.CompletedTask;`? If yes - state machine will check that task is already completed and will just continue method execution without returning the control to the caller.

Comment: @MetroSmurf like potentially can be observed [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEUCuA7NAExAGoAfAAQCYBGAWACgKAGAAgpoFYBuRxjgJwAKAESAeDcAg+yICUvBowBuAQyisMNVqwC8rALI0hs/jWEilAMwwxVNGXMUq1VbXqqG5g0RauqqdvkwC7EgAdADqABYweACCADZxQuqYVEbyTAAcwXoG0owA3oyaFEEUoQDCEAC2AA5xMFaEZXKaxSaiVbZpAL4B/FllroYFReyloQCaAJYwcYTuo22mVX49QA==)

Comment: Interesting. So, in the OP's case, is it fair to say (based on your suggested code) as soon as `ExecuteAsync` is invoked, it will return back to the caller, and then at some point return back to `ExecuteAsync` and run the rest of the method (wait loop in OP's first example)? (pretty cool example, btw)

Answer (score 0):

The `ExecuteAsync` is an [`async`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async) method, and `async` methods return a `Task` when the first `await` of an incomplete awaitable is reached. Your initial `ExecuteAsync` implementation contains no `await`, so the method will return when the `while` loop completes, which might never happen. The solution to this problem is to offload the loop to a [`ThreadPool`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool) thread using the [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) method:

```
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested )
            Console.WriteLine("running");
    });
}
```

This way the `ExecuteAsync` will return a `Task` practically instantly. This `Task` represents the completion of the code that is offloaded to the `ThreadPool`.