# How to run BackgroundService by counter using Task?

Tags: c#, .net-core, task-parallel-library, background-service

I have a background service in my dot net core application. That will run by capacity counter.

```
public class WebWorkGenerator : BackgroundService
{
    private const int ConsumeCapacityPerMinute = 10;
    private  int _capacityCounter;
    
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            while (ConsumeCapacityPerMinute - _capacityCounter > 0)
            {
                _capacityCounter++;

                Console.WriteLine($"Working {_capacityCounter}/{ConsumeCapacityPerMinute}");

                Task.Run(ProcessItems,stoppingToken);
            }
        }

        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task ProcessItems()
    {
        await Task.Delay(new Random().Next(1000, 5000));
      
        _capacityCounter--;
        
        Console.WriteLine("Processed.");
    }

}
```

Background job will run until 10, because ProcessItem() send requests to another service its capacity is 10.

ProcessItems() decrease the counter if item is processed. But my response is like following:

```
Working 1/10
Working 2/10
Working 3/10
Working 4/10
Working 5/10
Working 6/10
Working 7/10
Working 8/10
Working 9/10
Working 10/10
```

And does anything else. But when `Task.Run(ProcessItems,stoppingToken);` executed the `_capacityCounter` should be decreased and while loop must continue.
How can it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all there are several problems with your code:

- `_capacityCounter` is incremented/decremented in non-thread safe manner which can cause concurrency problems (can be fixed with `Interlocked.Increment/Decrement`)
- `ExecuteAsync` does not perform `await` correctly and as soon as possible (`await Task.CompletedTask;` is pointless from returning control to the caller point of view and combined with hosted services can lead to some problems - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73534497/2501279) for example)
- Assuming `ProcessItems` is "truly" async, then there is no need to wrap it in an extra `Task.Run`

As for the question itself - if the goal is to have at most 10 concurrently running "process" tasks then [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=net-8.0) seems to be an appropriate [synchronization primitive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/overview-of-synchronization-primitives) here:

```
public class WebWorkGenerator : BackgroundService
{
    private SemaphoreSlim _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(10);
    
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await _semaphore.WaitAsync();
            _ = ProcessItems();
        }
    }

    private async Task ProcessItems()
    {
        try
        {
            await Task.Delay(Random.Shared.Next(1000, 5000));
        }
        finally
        {
            _semaphore.Release();
            Console.WriteLine("Processed.");
        }
    }
}
```

If you want a bit more complex logic using the `ConsumeCapacityPerMinute` then you need to look into using some kind of rate limiting approach, for example via [build-in rate limiter API (available since .NET 7)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-rate-limiting-for-dotnet/) or from 3rd party library like `Polly` (see [example from their docs](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/blob/main/docs/strategies/rate-limiter.md/)).

Comment: In this stuation, 10 task taked to preocess and any of them complated the other next item will be process, am I right?

Comment: @barteloma yes, semaphore will block the next task instantiation until one of the previous will finish and release the semaphore.

Comment: it does not wait until first 10 process, only one complated, the other one goes in ok.

Comment: @barteloma yes, it starts a new one as soon as any one of the previously started finishes. What is your goal? To wait for all 10 to complete and than start next batch?